# How to Select all Entries that have the Same Values in One Column, but different Corresponding Values in another Column?

Tags: sql, oracle

I work in a Factory that makes Computer Chips.

We identify the Batches of Computer Chips Produced by ‘Lot IDs’

We also identify Batches of several Consumables used in the Manufacture of these Chips
by 'Lot IDs'  of an Identical Format.

This Information is stored in a Table called MM_LOT_INV_ST_LG in an Oracle Database.
A portion of this table is shown below:

| LOT_ID | MATERIAL_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1000585855 | Chips Batch 1 |
| 1000585856 | Chips Batch 2 |
| 1000586452 | SMD Tape Batch 1 |
| 1000586453 | SMD Tape Batch 2 |
| 1000456987 | Cover Tape Batch 1 |

(SMD Tape and Cover Tape are two different Consumable items.)

Lot IDs should only be used once.
For example above, Lot ID 1000585855, relates to a Computer Chips batch.
It should NEVER be reused - not even for another Computer Chips Batch.

I recall once however, a Computer Chip Batch and an SMD Tape Batch were assigned the same LOT ID.

**Is there a way for me to write an SQL Query to extract Lot IDs that are shared between different MATERIAL_IDs?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HAVIN COUNT DISTINCT`

I have added one duplicate row for showing that it works

```
CREATE TABLE MM_LOT_INV_ST_LG 
    ("LOT_ID" int, "MATERIAL_ID" varchar2(18))
;
```

```
INSERT ALL 
    INTO MM_LOT_INV_ST_LG  ("LOT_ID", "MATERIAL_ID")
         VALUES (1000585855, 'Chips Batch 1')
    INTO MM_LOT_INV_ST_LG  ("LOT_ID", "MATERIAL_ID")
         VALUES (1000585856, 'Chips Batch 2')
    INTO MM_LOT_INV_ST_LG  ("LOT_ID", "MATERIAL_ID")
         VALUES (1000586452, 'SMD Tape Batch 1')
    INTO MM_LOT_INV_ST_LG  ("LOT_ID", "MATERIAL_ID")
         VALUES (1000586453, 'SMD Tape Batch 2')
    INTO MM_LOT_INV_ST_LG  ("LOT_ID", "MATERIAL_ID")
         VALUES (1000456987, 'Cover Tape Batch 1')
      INTO MM_LOT_INV_ST_LG  ("LOT_ID", "MATERIAL_ID")
         VALUES (1000456987, 'Cover Tape Batch 5')
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

```
6 rows affected
```

```
SELECT "LOT_ID" FROM MM_LOT_INV_ST_LG GROUP BY "LOT_ID" HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT "MATERIAL_ID") > 1
```

| LOT_ID |
| --- |
| 1000456987 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/u7f6mbbg)

IF they have all INT in common you, can simply exculde them

```
CREATE TABLE MM_LOT_INV_ST_LG 
    ("LOT_ID" int, "MATERIAL_ID" varchar2(40))
;
```

```
INSERT ALL 
    INTO MM_LOT_INV_ST_LG  ("LOT_ID", "MATERIAL_ID")
         VALUES (1000585855, 'Chips Batch 1')
    INTO MM_LOT_INV_ST_LG  ("LOT_ID", "MATERIAL_ID")
         VALUES (1000585856, 'Chips Batch 2')
    INTO MM_LOT_INV_ST_LG  ("LOT_ID", "MATERIAL_ID")
         VALUES (1000586452, 'SMD Tape Batch 1')
    INTO MM_LOT_INV_ST_LG  ("LOT_ID", "MATERIAL_ID")
         VALUES (1000586453, 'SMD Tape Batch 2')
    INTO MM_LOT_INV_ST_LG  ("LOT_ID", "MATERIAL_ID")
         VALUES (1000456987, 'Cover Tape Batch 1')
      INTO MM_LOT_INV_ST_LG  ("LOT_ID", "MATERIAL_ID")
         VALUES (1000456987, 'INT Cover Tape Batch 5')
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

```
6 rows affected
```

```
SELECT "LOT_ID"  a FROM MM_LOT_INV_ST_LG 
  WHERE SUBSTR("MATERIAL_ID",1,3) <> 'INT' 
  GROUP BY "LOT_ID"
  HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT "MATERIAL_ID") > 1
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/4RuA6PBi)

Comment: Thank You!

This worked, except that I forgot to mention that there is one Exception to Lot IDs being shared. 

The Computer Chips (Let's take Chips Batch 1 as an example) only have MATERIAL_ID as 'Chips Batch 1' when they are finished processing.

At an earlier stage in their manufacturing process, they are called 'INT Chips Batch 1'.

So LOT ID 1000585855 appears twice:
- Once for 'Chips Batch 1'
- Once for 'INT Chips Batch 1'


Is there any way to ignore these entries that are shared?

Comment: if all have INT in common see edited answer